# Remove line break in the command prompt's output

Tags: shell, cmd, openssl, newline, command-prompt

I use command prompt (in windows) to run OpenSSL commands. I use the following command

```
openssl req -pubkey -in X.csr -noout
```

And I get the following output:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DBQcDQgAEDKaFsAauoh2mx418VYbZRButDnbl
wwWlth8Bkb+XV8gwh7399Ite0lkUhQcSAyEu6Xm7DhDSW28a54t0AQiQSw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I would like to get the output in a single line (without line break), something like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DBQcDQgAEDKaFsAauoh2mx418VYbZRButDnblwwWlth8Bkb+XV8gwh7399Ite0lkUhQcSAyEu6Xm7DhDSW28a54t0AQiQSw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

(Or) just like the one below

```
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DBQcDQgAEDKaFsAauoh2mx418VYbZRButDnblwwWlth8Bkb+XV8gwh7399Ite0lkUhQcSAyEu6Xm7DhDSW28a54t0AQiQSw==
```

Could anyone help on this ?,

Comment: Well, I don't know whether `openssl` supports a command line option to alter the output format, so look up the documentation. If there is no such, you could use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture the output text and (mis-)use [`set /P`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) to output each line without trailing line-break, like this: `for /F "delims= eol=-" %L in ('openssl req -pubkey -in X.csr -noout') do < nul set /P ="%L"` (do not forget to double up the `%`-signs when you want to use that code in a batch file)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to capture the output text and (mis-)use [`set /P`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) to output each line without trailing line-break, like this:

```cmd
for /F "delims= eol=-" %L in ('openssl req -pubkey -in X.csr -noout') do < nul set /P ="%L"
```

The option `eol=-` lets the header and footer lines be skipped by `for /F` as they begin with a hyphen.
(Although there are variants of Base64-encoding that use the `-`, it appears that you do not have such in your data as there is a `+`-sign, but this depends on the tool `OpenSSL` you are using.)

Do not forget to double up the `%`-signs when you want to use that code in a batch file!

Comment: No (mis)use at all. Redirection and `set /P` is pretty much a standard use...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I used the term "(mis-)use" since the intended purpose of `set /P` is to prompt for the value of a variable while I am using it as an alternative to the `echo` command that does not append a line-break, which might not be obvious, particularly for users that are not quite experienced with [tag:cmd]…